# How to validate user exist in yammer network

Tags: single-sign-on, yammer

I have SSO enabled and it is working fine with user who have registered in yammer but it gives error with user who have not yet registered in yammer 
:::how to listen SSO error:::

Blow code used for SSO

```
        if (yamNetwork != null) {

            $.getScript("https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js", function () {


                // Load Yammer Comment control
                yam.connect.embedFeed({
                    container: "#yammerComment",
                    network: "org.com",
                    feedType: "open-graph",
                    objectProperties: {
                        type: "page",
                        title: document.title.toString()
                    },
                    config: {
                        use_sso: true,
                        header: false,
                        footer: false,
                        promptText: "Comment on this page",
                        defaultToCanonical: true
                    }
                });
            }
                    );





        }
```

but unable to receive any response

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code you can authenticate user on yammer. For successful authentications you will get the "authenticationResponse".

```
   string authorizeCode = Request.Params.Get("code");
    var yammerClientID = your client id;
    var yammerClientSecret = your client secret;
    string authenticateUrl = String.Format("https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&code={2}", yammerClientID, yammerClientSecret, authorizeCode);
    try
    {
    authenticationResponse = cli.DownloadString(authenticateUrl);
    }
    catch
    {
    //Code                                        
    }
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, then please share your code here.

Comment: I have updated  my question , so which code required in Request.Params.Get method

Comment: Refer this article for complete code:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/838663/Building-an-OAuth-Yammer-App-with-ASP-Net-MVC-and